# How to get response from network if my data is in array list

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to get response from the network which is an array list and send that array list to next activity so that I can display it in my recyclerView.

```
public void sendPost(){
        Call<List<SearchModel>> call = mAPIService.sendSearch("1","2");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SearchModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<SearchModel>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<SearchModel>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Responce " +response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    SearchModel searchResponse = response.body().get(0);
                    assert searchResponse != null;

                    searchModelList.add(searchResponse);
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultsSearch.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("mylist",searchModelList);
                    intent1.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something is error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<SearchModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("msg","Failed "+t);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And also when I send a single data by storing this value `response.body().get(0)` in my model,my app crashes. How can I solve these errors.
I am getting the value in next activity like this:

```
public class ResultsSearch extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent mIntent;
    List vehicleResponse;
    Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results_search);

        bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        init();


    }
    private void init(){

        vehicleResponse = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(vehicleResponse,getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);


    }
}
```

Comment: crashes with what error?

Comment: by the way, maybe you should be using `putParcelableArrayList` instead of `putSerializable`

Comment: but how do I get all the list without getting the data with index `response.body().get(0)`

Comment: if I use this `response.body().get(0)` i get only a single value but it contains multiple values. How to store all the value without using index so that i can display it  in recyclerView

Comment: notice we don't see the api you're using, I don't know what is being returned by reading this code. The usual thing I'm used to is that the response body is a json or xml data representation and should be parsed,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the SearchModel is parcelable.
But the right way is to pass parameters of search in the Bundle and make the API call on the ResultsSearch

Comment: I made the API call in the ResultSearch but i am not getting response as of early.
and when i use `searchModelList.add(searchResponse);` then it gives value 0,but there is data in the api